# Code for anchor

Tags: html, anchor, fixed

I've a problem with anchor. I've icons with fixed position that should link to an anchor in the same page.
I've written the html code, but something is probably wrong.

Here the website: http://montedominimusicantiqua.altervista.org

and here part of the code of on image with link:

```
<a href="#ancora-video">
  <img src="icon-video-g.png"
       style="position:fixed; left:5px; top:5px; width:45px; height:45px; border:none;"
       alt="video"
       title="Live Streaming e Archivio Video" 
       onmouseover="this.src='icon-video.png'" 
       onmouseout="this.src='icon-video-g.png'"/>
</a>
```

and the code of an anchor:

```
<a name=”ancora-persone”></a>persone <div class="box1"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id="ancora-video"></a>persone <div class="box1"></div>
```

**Note:** When you use anchor, use `id` or `data` html5 attribute

Answer (score 0):

Refer this site, for better explanation :

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000049.htm

Its clearly mentioned that when we try to link within the page, Once user clicks on the anchor element it will try to search the name attribute (although name is deprecated in XHTML).

We should use "name" attribute instead of "id" attribute because HTML5 will create global variable if we use "id". So instead of polluting the global namespace, declare "name" attribute.

```html
<a href="#ancora-video"><img src="icon-video-g.png" style="position:fixed; left:5px; top:5px; width:45px; height:45px; border:none;" alt="video" title="Live Streaming e Archivio Video" onmouseover="this.src='icon-video.png'" onmouseout="this.src='icon-video-g.png'"/></a>
<a name="ancora-video"></a>persone <div class="box1"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think that it was only the use of **”** instead of **"** !!!
sorry!